# How to make an inner join between 2 table with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, jpql

How to write a JPA query that make a join between 2 entities that doesn't share any reference between them I mean no Relation has been defined in the mapping

```
EntityA
@Id
long id

String field1
String field2

EntityB
@Id
String field1
@Id
String field2
```

How can I write a join like This in JPQL

```
select entityB from entityA,entityB
where entityB.field1 = entityA.field1
and entityB.field2 = entityA.field2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking in SQL, not ORM.  In ORM, you create relationships between entities (`@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, `@ManyToMany`, etc.), and the ORM uses those relationships to determine how it should join them together.

You need to update your entities to have those relationships, and then traverse the object model to do what your want to do.

Here is a place to get started: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association

Comment: OK get this but I don't want to create database constraint and create this relation will generate such constraints how can I define such relation without generate database constraints ?

Comment: You can run Hibernate without generating constraints - just don't configure `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't any explicit relationships between these entities, it is not possible to perform any explicit join in JPQL.

You can always write down the query as a cartesian product. Depending on the RDBMS you're using it might be optimizing the query to be nearly as efficient as a join. However, take into account that the physical model will have to be optimised to that effect. That means indexes, and if possible foreign keys. Without having those, this query will be highly inefficient compared with a join.